# Get custom classes in Wordpress Navigation Menu

Tags: menus, customization, icon

i'm a beginner to Wordpress. I have a question is how to get only classes we put in CSS classes box in Navigation Menu? Not all with the default Wordpress classes. The purpose of this is i want to make a FontAwesome icon before each list in Navigation Menu.

Comment: You can simple add `<i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home` in your navigation labels. This will add icons without any issue.

Comment: Well, that is so simple! Thank you @Roberthue! Really appreciating!

Comment: Sure no problem. :)

Comment: Where have you added these? I meant in menu items, not on page titles.

Comment: But @Roberthue in the title attributes of source codes, it display like `title="&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-home&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt; Home"`. It look so bad! Any idea?

Comment: I added more info in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easy way or hard way. Hard way would be you creating custom functions to remove all menu classes and add `FontAwesome icons` accordingly.

And easy way would be this.

Go to Appearance > Menus

And add `FontAwesome icons` in menu items. Like this.

[image: menu]

**Note:** You don't need to change page titles on each page. Just menu labels.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot that i has rewritten wp_nav_menu rules. Thank again for your quick answer and responses! Problem solved. :)

Comment: That's great! Let us know if you still face any issue. Previously I was also looking for similar solution and was trying to modify menu with `Walker Class` but then one of my friend suggest this easy-pezy method. :)